# conversion from 'long' to 'int' and warnings

Tags: c

Why there is a warning for c) but not a warning for b)?

I'm assigning in both cases a `long` value to an `int`.

```
   // INT32_MAX = 2147483647

   // a:
   int32_t a = 2147483647;

   // b:
   // no warning
   int32_t b = 1L;

   // c:
   // warning: implicit conversion from
   //'long' to 'int'
   int32_t c = 2147483648;
```

2147483648 doesn't fit into an `int` (but 1L does). Ist this the explanation for this behaviour? Do these warnings depend on current values? I was expecting two warnings and not just one.

EDIT:
compiler: clang version 13.0.0

I still have problems to understand that. Ok, `1L` fits into an integer of type `int`.

So there are no warnings for the following line of code:

```
    // no warning
   int b = 1L;
```

But why do I get warnings for almost the same code? Because I initialize it with a variable value? But it still fits into this variable.

```
   // warning
   long temp = 1L;
   int a = temp;
```

There are no warnings after changing `temp` to a `const` value:

```
   // no warning
   const long temp = 1L;
   int a = temp;
```

Comment: Because `1L` can be cast to an `int32_t` without overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Values of expressions of type `int` and `long` are **numbers** (in mathematical sense). This is not spelled out explicitly in the standard, but can be inferred from the language that talks about ranges of types, for example:

> [6.2.5/8](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p8) 8 For any two integer types with the same signedness and different integer conversion rank (see 6.3.1.1), the range of values of the type with smaller integer conversion rank is a subrange of the values of the other type.

The value of the expression `1L` (of type `long`) is the number 1. The value of the expression `2147483648` (of some type which in your implementation is *not* `int`) is the number 2147483648. The former belongs to the range of values of the type `int`, so there is no warning. The latter doesn't, so there is a warning: the value **does not** fit.

```
long temp = 1L;
int a = temp;
```

`temp` is not a constant. Its value can, in principle, be anything that fits in a `long`. Anything that fits in a `long` does not necessarily fit in an `int`, so there is a *different* warning: the value **might not** fit. This actually never happens in this program, but the compiler is not obliged to see that. Such things are impossible to prove in general, so your compiler doesn't try even in this simple case.

```
const long temp = 1L;
int a = temp;
```

`temp` is a constant. Its value is 1, and it cannot be anything other than 1. Your compiler is able to easily prove it, so it does.

Note, not all compilers do any or all of the above. There is no obligation in the standard to emit warnings.

Answer (score 0):

When `long` is converted to an `int32_t` or an `int`, the source value **might** not fit in the destination, depending on circumstances.

In `int32_t b = 1L;`, the compiler sees that `1L` has the value one and fits in an `int32_t`, so it does not warn you.

In `int32_t c = 2147483648;`, the value does not fit in an `int32_t` (in this C implementation), so the compiler warns you.